# Flash Builder: Mobile AS3 Project or Mobile Flex Project?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, mobile

This month I started to play with Flash Builder because I don't have a mac to create native iPhone apps.

I have made a Flex Mobile Project and an AS3 Mobile project. Both do mostly exact the same and I see great differences in operation speed (AS3 version is much faster). Also the size of the AS3 version is less than the size of the Flex version when I deploy the project.

But one thing disappoints me, the size of a deployed AS3 app (Android) is still about 8MB. I think that is quite huge for a simple app, or is it normal? I did not test the iOS version because I am not an Apple Developer member (is there a trick to deploy an iOS app with fake certificates)?

Resources I have used in the apps:

- Two images approx. 35kb in size
- A StageWebView

I want to know:

- What is the average size of a simple app when it is a native app (apk file)?
- What is the difference between an AS3 app and a Flex app except the libraries that re used?
- Is the AS3 app converted to C or another language?
- Why is the apk so huge (IMO)?
- Is there a trick to deploy an iOS app with fake certificates? (just for testing)

Thanks for the answer(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like to use `Mobile AS3 Project` if you want you apps to be smaller and your GUI mainly contains vector graphics and `Mobile Flex Project` if you prefer to use standart GUI Controls that comes together with Flex framework but adds overhead in size because of controls that come with it.

As of the other questions:

- the size of the apps is different on mobile platforms. Typical iOS app is about 2MB - 20MB. It really depends on resources you  store with your app. What might be important to you is not to overcome 20MB if not needed because 20MB+ apps require Wi-Fi connection to be downloaded.
  (However you should export `release` build version only as mentioned by www.Flextras.com)
- there is no fundamental difference between AS3 and Flex apps - they both compile to the same instructions that executes on targeted mobile platform.
- as far as I know (being iOS developer myself) there is no workaround to deploy an iOS apps. You need to use Mac and become Apple Developer to deploy with valid certificate.
- to make your app smaller try to pai special attention to the resources you add to the project. Although I believe the size is so big because of framework itself, you would like to use more vector graphics vs. bitmaps when compiling apps with Flash/Flex.

Comment: I was pretty sure that you only need a Mac to upload to the app store.  Everything else can be done on Windows and there a bunch of tutorials about such things.

Comment: Thanks man for your "sweet" answer. But it seems that 8MB is not that bad even when you use a webview to show some content. Because of the policy (and the usage of a WebView) at Apple i wonder if it can make pass the tests to be a 'native' app. I don't like the idea that it is needed to be an Apple Developer to play around making apps for the iDevices. I've already registred myself as Apple Developer but get stuck on the information they want. I am a starting company that wants to register things when it is for sure only (because of the costs involved). About the graphics: They are vrysmall.

Comment: Thanks man for your "sweet" answer. With "sweet" i mean that i appreciate your answer. I have compared the produced SWF's, the AS3 is much smaller. I know already that it is not converted to native code, you still need the flex framework, it is included in the apk file. Did you know that an apk file is a zip file?

Comment: You're welcome.
Yes, APK files are zip formated packages based on JAR file format. In case you have more questions or insights about Flash/Flex please contact me.

Comment: If this post answered your question, please select it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

> - What is the average size of a simple app when it is native app (apk file)?

I have no idea.  When you were comparing sizes; did you export a release build or a debug version?  The full version of my app; using Captive Runtime is 12MB.  That includes all the embedded images.  I thought that roughly 8MB is the size of the embedded runtime.  Of course, if you don't use Captive Runtime then the app will be smaller; but it will have a depency on the user having the runtime installed.

> - What is the difference between an AS3 app and a Flex app except the libraries that are used?

For all intents and purposes nothing.  The Flex Framework will need to execute code to setup the framework and such.  In theory this 'impact' is offset by the value that the framework brings.

```
- Is the AS3 app converted to C or other language?
```

Not for Android or Playbook.  It relies on the Mobile AIR Runtime--which I assume is written as a native app somehow.  For iOS there is a more in depth conversion taking place; but no on knows the exact magic sauce; but it the process is much more intensive than Android or Playbook and people believe that your code and the AIR Runtime is converted to Objective C somehow in a way that is not in violation of the Apple licensing agreement.

> - Why is the apk so huge (IMO)?

Huge is open to interpretation.  Without seeing your full app code; it's tough to judge.

> - Is there a trick to deploy an iOS app with fake certificates? (just for testing)

I don't think so; although there may be possibilities on unlocked devices.

Comment: Thanks man for your "sweet" answer. With "sweet" i mean that i appreciate your answer and the info. Interesting to read that there is a difference is in the android version comparing to iOS. Maybe it has something to do with java, AS3 is in a way similar to java?

Answer (score 0):

When you export for Android you have an option of embedding the air framework in the application, that way your users don't have to download air. you can export your application without air embed which will result in a much lighter application, however your users will need to download air runtime.   http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_do_I_create_an_AIR_application_for_Android_tha-19299.html

Comment: Ah, thanks. But i don't think that is an option (i think it is not smart to this).